# Can't keep local rotation after applying it to an object

Tags: transforms, mirror-modifier

I have a small problem.

Long story short, I'm working on a locker model and I want to keep the local rotation of the hinges (as this allows for the door to rotate without clipping into the locker). Sadly, when I apply rotation, it breaks. I do believe it also causes an issue with morroring the door, as they won't rotate the same way (even on local rotation mode).

[image]

Comment: When you apply rotation you're telling Blender that the current state of the object is it's default 0, 0, 0 rotation.
So if you want to keep local rotation you just shouldn't apply the rotation.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati what if I want to export the model into a game, in which case I need to apply all changes before doing so? Isn't there a way to set local rotation to be the "default" one?

Comment: What game engine are you using?

Comment: Maybe the best way would be rigging it with an armature.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati I'll be exporting the model into the Source Engine as a cosmetic item for Team Fortress 2.

Comment: What if you build the object so that its hinges are at local 0, 0, 0 when the door to the locker is shut? And then export it in the shut position? Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Okay, I downloaded the file and now I understand. The hinges are not perfectly vertical, they are a little tilted, that's why the initial rotation can't be 0, 0, 0.
I don't know the engine you're using, but it's my understanding that this sort of thing (things with hinges and moving parts) generally should be rigged with a skeleton (armature).